# Terraform logic app throwing error : not accepting input for workflow_parameters

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-logic-apps, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a Azure logic App workfow using terraform. My module is defined as below :

```
  resource "azurerm_logic_app_workflow" "logic_app_workflow" {
  for_each            = var.logic_app_workflows
  name                = each.value["name"]
  location            = each.value["location"]
  resource_group_name = each.value["resource_group_name"]
  enabled             = each.value["enabled"]
  workflow_parameters = { for k,v in each.value["workflow_parameters"] : k =>jsonencode(v) } 
  tags               = each.value["logic_app_workflow_tags"]
}
```

and my variable is defined as below :

```
 variable "logic_app_workflows" {
  type = map(object({
    name                    = string
    location                = string
    resource_group_name     = string
    enabled                 = bool
    workflow_parameters     = any
    logic_app_workflow_tags = map(string)
  }))
}
```

My tfvars file looks like this :

```
logic_app_workflows = {
  logic_app_workflow1 = {
    name                = "test-logic"    
    location            = "canadacentral" 
    resource_group_name = "test-rg"       
    enabled             = true
    workflow_parameters = {
      connection = {
        defaultValue = {}
        type         = { type = "Object" }
      }
    }
    logic_app_workflow_tags = {
      applicationName = "Logic App workflow"
    }
  }
}
```

Error :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I also received the same error when I tried your code in my environment.*

[image]

The issue is with the connection type parameter in `terraform.tfvars` file. The type of the connection workflow parameters should be in the format `type  = "Object"`because `type  = { type = "Object" }` is not valid `json` string according to the [workflow_parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#parameters).

***I modified `tfvars` file as shown***:

```bash
logic_app_workflows = {
  logic_app_workflow1 = {
    name                = "test-logic"    
    location            = "canadacentral" 
    resource_group_name = "Jahnavi"      
    enabled             = true
    workflow_parameters = {
      connection = {
        defaultValue = {}
        type         = "Object" 
      }
    }
    logic_app_workflow_tags = {
      applicationName = "Logic App workflow"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

***Apply completed:***

[image]

***Deployed and viewed in Portal:***

[image]